# python pandas: How to check if a column item is also item of a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, filter

I try to change specific values of an existing dataframe column if they met my conditions. What works fine with the following code, I'm sure that can be done in a more accurate way, but optimization is not the question for now.

My dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"list1": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  
                   "list2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
```

My code so far:

```
def function(var, x, y):
   print("DF before:", var, sep="\n", end="\n\n")
   cond = [var["list1"] == x, var["list1"] == y]
   choice = [True, True]
   var["test"] = np.select(cond, choice)
   var["copy"] = np.where(var["test"], var["list1"], 0)
   var["changed"] = var.apply(lambda row: row["copy"] + (x*y) if row["copy"] else 0, axis=1)
   var["list1"] = var.apply(lambda row: row["changed"] if row["changed"] != 0 else row["list1"], axis=1)
   print("manipulated DF:", var, sep="\n", end="\n\n")
   var.drop(["test", "copy", "changed"])
   print("clean manipulated DF:", var, sep="\n", end="\n\n")

function(df, x=2, y=5)
```

In my original code I have a few entries in my list each of which should return 'True' if met.
There starts the misere:
I tried to add the list as a new column to start the comparison over it. But since the list is only a kind of selection of the values from 'list1', it will never reach the same length.So the list would be something like `condition_list = [1, 3, 5]`.
Unfortunately I haven't found a way to adjust the length automatically, for example by inserting 0 for missing values. Even if, the next problem would be: The entries have to be on the correct position, so if the item of condition-list is 5, I need to have it in the 6th row of 'list1'.
So I thought with the above code I could just scan the column 'list1' for the entries and so change the values only for those specific entries. But I can't get this working. It just change either the first value of my column, with index 0 or every entry of my column or it happens nothing as all entries are set to False in `df["test"]`.
The problematic code looks like:

```
# list of entries have to be found in list1 to change values in list2
entries_to_met = [1, 3, 5]

def function2(var):
   print("DF before:", var, sep="\n", end="\n\n")
   cond = [var["list1"] == entries_to_met.item]
   choice = [True]
   var["test"] = np.select(cond, choice)
   var["copy"] = np.where(var["test"], var["list2"], 0)
   var["changed"] = var.apply(lambda row: row["copy"] + 15 if row["copy"] else 0, axis=1)
   var["list2"] = var.apply(lambda row: row["changed"] if row["changed"] != 0 else row["list2"], axis=1)
   print("manipulated DF:", var, sep="\n", end="\n\n")
   var.drop(["test", "copy", "changed"])
   print("clean manipulated DF:", var, sep="\n", end="\n\n")

function2(df)
```

I hope someone has an idea. If anything's not clear about that question: Feel free to ask.

### Edit

as it seems to need a better problem description: my Input looks like:

|  | list1 | list2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | 6 |

And my desired output, after the entries of `entries_to_met = [1, 3, 5]` are matched with the entries of list1, should look like:

|  | list1 | list2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 17 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 19 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | 21 |

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to understand the problem clearly. Can you specify your desired output for a given input?

Comment: If I set a list like "entries_to_met" I try to check every row of my DataFrame's column "list1" and if it matches, I want to change the according entry of column "list2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"list1": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   "list2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})

ltm = [1, 3, 5]

df.loc[df['list1'].isin(ltm), 'list2'] += 15
    
df
```

|  | list1 | list2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 17 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 19 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | 21 |

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
mask = (df['list1'].isin([1,3,5]))
df.loc[ mask, 'list2'] = df.loc[mask]['list2'] + 15
```

via numpy:

```
import numpy as np
mask = (df['list1'].isin([1,3,5]))
df['list2'] = np.where(mask, df['list2']+15, df['list2'])
```

Comment: So far the numpy-way worked fine, thank you. But it changes the first entry of 'list2' (index = 0), as well as its last entry (index = 6) too.

Comment: @Grinnorye updated my answer. I'll say go with `np.where`  it's much faster